# How to clear WPF Grid contents?

Tags: wpf

I want to clear/remove ALL the contents of a Grid including RowDefinitions, how can I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`myGrid.Children.Clear()` will remove all child controls nested in the grid.
`myGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear()` will remove all row definitions.
`myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear()` will remove all column definitions.

for the sake of completness, you can also add/remove single items through the add/remove methods of the appropriate collections.  `myGrid.Children` for controls, `myGrid.RowDefinitions` for row definitions, and `myGrid.ColumnDefinitions` for the columns.

all of this information is available [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx)

Comment: After I clear Children, the row count and column count remain unchanged though? Is it been well cleared?

Answer (score -2):

try to loop into your container control(Example a Grid) and in this loop check the type of the control like this :

```
     foreach(DependencyObject c in YourContainer.Children)
        {
            //If you only want to modify TextBoxes
            if(c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox")
            {
                //Erase Text property of all TextBoxes in my Grid Control
                ((TextBox)c).Text = "";


            }
        }
```

Comment: For modifying whis would be ok. But if you'd try to remove contents from the grid as OP asked originally, this approach would lead to exceptional behavior because you'd try to modify the collection while iterating over it. Furthermore, given your code, I'd suggest replacing the string comparison for type checks completely, e.g. by querying only the TextBoxes from the Children collection like so: foreach(TextBox c in YourContainer.Children.OfType<TextBox>)